# Drag posts and pages so you can sort them in order

Tags: posts, pages, wp-list-pages

So has anyone done this? can be done? On wordpress admin, when you click List Pages, or List posts, I want to make a drag&drop in order to sort the pages/posts, but before I start I want to know if someone has done it already, or if there is a plugin for this.

Answer (score 2):

The [My Page Order](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/my-page-order/) plugin provides an easy drag and drop interface for re-ordering pages and subpages (as well as a helpful option to make all the pages available directly from the pages menu in the dashboard).

Comment: This plugin is no longer available

Answer (score 1):

I've created a plugin called CMS Tree Page View that perhaps does what you are looking for.

From the description of the plugin: "Adds a tree of all your pages or custom posts. Use drag & drop to reorder your pages, and edit, view, add, and search your pages.".

You can find it at the WordPress plugin repository:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cms-tree-page-view/

Thre are some more alternatives too:

- [CMS Page Order](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cms-page-order/) (looks even better than my own plugin :)
- [Admin Menu Tree Page View](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-menu-tree-page-view/)
- [Simple Page Ordering](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-page-ordering/)

Comment: In 2021 the Simple Page Ordering plugin is still being updated, and works brilliantly!

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugins out there that create the drag and drop functionality and the best one I've used is  [**Post Types Order**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-types-order/)

Comment: As far as I see, Post types order..implements a section in the posts to re-order them, I want this thing to work on the built in list pages/list posts section

Comment: it does just that for any post type you have, post, pages or any custom type.

Answer (score -2):

There is plugin out there for this:

[pageMash](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pagemash/)

> Manage your multitude of pages with pageMash's slick drag-and-drop style, ajax interface. Allows for quick sorting, hiding and organising of page pare

Comment: It looks like is outdated, I'm gonna try it out!

Comment: An answer should be [more than a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion).

Comment: @toscho just cos it's just a link doesn't mean it's not an answer..

Comment: @Uffo I've been using it on WordPress 3.3.1 and works fine.

Comment: When the linked site changes or vanishes the answer isn’t an answer anymore. That’s why we expect at least a useful description.